# Upload file with the given destination path in java

Tags: java, file-upload

In a java web application (struts) runs on tomcat, I need to upload a file (of any type) to a destination folder which will be taken as input parameter from the user. The destination can not only within the server directory but also anywhere in the system. Is there any api available for file upload or can this be acheived using java IO? Any suggestions with sample code will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Do you really want to let anyone on the web create a file anywhere they wish on your server?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Yes I have tried the above mentioned scenario, but using servlet concept, which will get the realpath on the server (ie., using ServletConfig.getServletContext().getRealPath()) which obviously will upload file in the server directory. But I want a standalone upload functionality where the user can specify any destination on the system to upload.

Comment: that is suicidal. If you're looking for a "file manager" type of capability, it still has to be restrained by the normal file system security of the host.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing "user.dir" property which has path of server directory. Here is sample code may be of some help

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", <destination path on your system>);

File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `common-fileupload`. There are more example for that [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html).